# Extracting the Java class that a method belongs to for a method invocation when parsing Java source code

Tags: java, class, parsing, types

I was trying to parse a Java source file.
For example, for the following code:

```java
...
public void testHeaderMissingWithNull() throws Exception {
   final Reader in = new StringReader("a,,c,,d\n1,2,3,4\nx,y,z,zz");
   CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader().withNullString("").withIgnoreEmptyHeaders(true).parse(in).iterator();
}
...
```

Is it possible to extract the fully qualified class name of the class where the method `withIgnoreEmptyHeaders` comes from?

Comment: Isn’t javalang source-only? To get class information you’d need to introspect the return value of the method (although in this case it’s `CSVFormat` because it’s using a fluent interface). *(There’s other ways the information could be gotten, for example, if you have the source for CSVFormat, you could find the method and its signature.)

Comment: Do you have a class path? If you just have the source file only, it is not possible in general. For example, consider `Foo.returnsBar().someBarMethod()`. To find out which class `someBarMethod()` belongs to, you have to find out what type `returnsBar()` returns, but `returnsBar` is declared in another file, or even, only in some .class file that is in the class path, and there is no source code for `Foo`.

Comment: Either way, this is not a trivial thing to do at all. How about compiling the Java file first, then look into .class file to see where the methods belong? Each method call in bytecode needs to include the class where the method belongs, after all.